# Run Python function (64-bit) from C# in 32-bit program

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, uipath

after quite long inspection of this issue, I'm a little bit lost and I need community help. Let me explain the issue firstly:

I'm using the software (32-bit, let's call it UiPath) in Windows 7 (x64). From UiPath, I want to run python method by using Python 3.6 (64-bit) Interpreter. In UiPath, you can write your own activity programmed in C#. My goal is to write the activity (C# class), which will be able to run some python function with parameters and return me output (return) of this function.

I think, that cmd is not the good approach, maybe IronPython would help me, but can you give me any advice, please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I can think of various ways to do this, but I'm not familiar with IronPython... but I found this: https://medium.com/emoney-engineering/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5  which appears to be almost exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Though I *think* it seems this would run everything in 32 bit processes (could be wrong) - is there something about what you're doing that specifically requires 64 bit, or is it simply that the interpreter you have is a 64 bit version?

Comment: Thanks @GPW for you answer. Actually the only reason, why I would like to use 64-bit interpreter is just because of the performance. Btw. there is some recommendation by software provider: you can write python code, but need to run it outside the robot, as the current version only has a 32bit runtime (not compatible with most ML frameworks).

Easiest thing to do is to host the model in another program, and create an activity that integrates with that program. Do you have any recommendation, how to do that?

Comment: I've added an answer detailing roughly what I'd do I think.  There are other approaches, but this is fairly straightforward and something I've done myself in similar situations...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know you stated you'd like to avoid using cmd, but since you're basically trying to execute a 64-bit process from a 32-bit one you'll always end up having to do a workaround which does something like that as it can't host it in-process.

I created a quick sample solution (Visual Studio 2017) here:
https://github.com/Moobylicious/RunExternalProcessExample/archive/master.zip

This contains two console projects - one is 64 bit and one 32 bit.  the 32-bit one calls the 64 bit by creating a process (command line in effect, but hidden).  it then displays the output of this.

If you just run the solution as-is it should run the 32-bit console app, which will call the 64-bit one.

The main code to run an external process like this is below.  The version in the sample is the Main() method of a console app, but you'd probably have to put this into a class library or whatever is required for a plugin/activity/thingy for your specific need.

```
public int RunProgram()
{
    //create  process to run an external program...
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    //hide it - don't spawn a CMD window
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

    //add command line params - guess these would be passed in somehow?
    var arg1 = "function_name";
    var arg2 = "input1";
    var arg3 = "input2";

    //Build command line. 
    startInfo.Arguments = $@"/C c:\path\to\python\Some64BitProcess.exe {arg1} {arg2} {arg3}";

    //I don't know what the output of this will be.  whether it creates a file or 
    //just prints stuff out on the command line (STDOUT).  
    //it is possible to capture STDOUT into a stream, but for simplicity I'll simply re-direct it into
    //an output file via the command line '>' which will overwrite any file already there.
    startInfo.Arguments += " > output.txt";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    //Run process
    process.Start();

    //wait for it to complete - note, if this process pauses for user input at 
    //any point this will basically just hang indefinitely.
    //you CAN pipe a 'Y' into it or something to avoid this(simulate a keypress), 
    //but would be better to work out command line
    //switches that supress any waiting for user input.
    process.WaitForExit();

    //now, we can get results.

    var output = File.ReadAllText("output.txt");

    //Do things with output?
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.ReadLine();

    //process.ExitCode is the Exit Code of the command.  This might be useful as it might 
    //indicate specific errors encountered
    //by Python.
    return process.ExitCode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, GPW, it seems exactly, what I needed! Let me evaluate this solution and in case it will work, let me close this question :).

Comment: no problem.  I've used this basic approach for various things and it works fairly well.  Of course there are always potentially edge cases which cause problems and those can be hard to debug as the process is entirely separate, but I recommend logging the exact command line somewhere so you can easily run it manually to try to work out what happened.